# How to get all UniProt results as tsv for query

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm looking for a programmatic way to get all the Uniprot ids and sequences (Swiss-Prot + TrEMBL) for a given protein length  but if I run my query I get only first 25 results. Is there any way to run a loop to get them all?

My code:

```
import requests, sys

WEBSITE_API = "https://rest.uniprot.org"

# Helper function to download data
def get_url(url, **kwargs):
  response = requests.get(url, **kwargs);

  if not response.ok:
    print(response.text)
    response.raise_for_status()
    sys.exit()

  return response


r = get_url(f"{WEBSITE_API}/uniprotkb/search?query=length%3A%5B100%20TO%20109%5D&fields=id,accession,length,sequence", headers={"Accept": "text/plain; format=tsv"})

with open("request.txt","w") as file:
  file.write(r.text)
```

Comment: For others looking to query UniProt progammatically with Python and get back TSV-formatted results, that is built in to a Python package called [Unipressed](https://multimeric.github.io/Unipressed/), that works with UniProt's new REST API. One of the formats you can choose to get the data back in is tsv, as listed in the documentation under 'Advantages' at present. See an example, with tsv format and linking to an example saving TSV-formatted text as a file [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/286919/#9537049). I don't know about the limit though on what it returns number-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a different url which seems to be working to give back more/all results. It was taking a long time to return all ~5M, so I've restricted it to just 10,000 right now

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io


# Helper function to download data
def get_url(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, **kwargs);

    if not response.ok:
        print(response.text)
        response.raise_for_status()
        sys.exit()

    return response

#create the url
base_url = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=length:[100%20TO%20109]'

additional_fields = [
    '&format=tab',
    '&limit=10000', #currently limiting the number of returned results, comment out this line to get all output
    '&columns=id,accession,length,sequence',
]

url = base_url+''.join(additional_fields)
print(url)

#get the results as a large pandas table
r = get_url(url)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text),sep='\t')
df
```

Output:
[image]